# Kendo Textbox Validation : click twice issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Click or submit event doesn't fire soon after the textbox validation failure  happens

Please try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6nw8s/37/) to reproduce the issue.

HTML:

```
<div id="tickets">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:text-top;">Document Name&nbsp;*</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:435px;">
                <input name="Name" required></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="k-button" id="btnSubmit">Click me</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var validator = $("#tickets").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

     $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
         alert("Select valid value");
         event.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Steps

1. Focus on the textbox by clicking on it
2. Try clicking the button with textbox empty, the validation displays
   as expected.
3. Type in some values into the textbox
4. Click the button again, 'click' event doesn't fire as expected(But works fine when user
   clicks the second time)

This is weird whenever the user needs to click on the submit button twice to perform the action after a validation failure.

I found this behavior mainly with textbox control.

Comment: I have same problem too, but I didn't much care about it. If you insist on solving this problem, you can try show validation message at right of the text box, so button won't go down and you can click the first time

Comment: @user2413664 It's not an issue on textbox focusout event kendo script remove required validation that's why your click event is not fire.because both event fire same time. so Don't worry it is kendo behavior.

Comment: since you already know jsfiddle: try using the "Tidy Up" button in the top menu

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you click button, validation happends because validateOnBlur is turned on.
Set Validator validateOnBlur to false.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/validator#configuration-validateOnBlur

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce with a current version of Kendo UI and was unable to.
This here will work as expected (going through your steps, it will print "not valid",then "valid"):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var validator = $("#tickets").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

     $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
         if (validator.validate()) {
             console.log("valid");
         } else {
             console.log("not valid");
         }
     });
 });
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/uz6V8/1/))

Comment: "The version was not the problem." If you remove the CSS from my Jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6nw8s/37/), it works !!!!!!